# Unresolved function or method sendFile(), express/nodejs using WebStorm

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm, the code is working fine, but WebStorm is throwing a warning that it can't resolve `sendFile()` which is a part of expressjs. This is more of a nuisance than a problem.

```js
let express = require("express")

let app = express();

app.get("/u/:id", function(req, res){
    let profileID = req.params.id;
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
});


app.listen(3000);
```

[image: screenshot of some code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`express` methods are generated dynamically in runtime, so they can't be resolved during static code analysis. Installing TypeScript stubs should help to get methods resolved: put cursor on `'express'` in `let express = require('express');`, hit `Alt+Enter` and choose **Install TypeScript definitions for better type information** to install typings - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files

[image]

Comment: How to perform this on intelliJ?

Comment: Instructions are the same for all JetBrains IDEs, nothing specific to WebStorm here

Answer (score 0):

res.sendFile() is supported by Express v4.8.0 onwards.

Comment: How do I tell WebStorm that? The code works fine, its just WebStorm thinks its missing...

Comment: i think webstorm is based on the latest versions of technologies in which you coded to display warnings

Comment: I personally use visual studio